Account for dynamic require in Rollup
I'm trying to build a project, but I have a problem.
This is the structure of my project:
.
├── deps
│   ├── deps.js
│   └── package.json
└── module1
    ├── mod1.js
    ├── package.json
    ├── rollup.config.js
    └── test.js

mod1.js is using a dynamic require to import deps.js.
When I test my code, I get this error:
Error: Could not dynamically require "deps". Please configure the dynamicRequireTargets or/and ignoreDynamicRequires option of @rollup/plugin-commonjs appropriately for this require call to work.
Can anyone help me?
I configured my Rollup with this:
`

commonjs({
    dynamicRequireTargets: [
        "../deps/deps.js",
    ],
})


but it's still not working.
